# Tree View W/ the Vertical Nav

Tags: vmware-clarity, clarity

Is there a way to create a deeper tree using the vertical nav? Using the clr-vertical-nav-group and clr-vertical-nav-group-children Im only able to go as far as the first layer deep. I want to be able to have 3 or for more layers like this..

- section 1

  - subsection 1

    - content 1
  - subsection 2

    - content 2
- section 2

  - subsection 1

    - content 1
  - subsection 2

    - content 2

Comment: Yes You can N level of tree using clarity tree components but you need to use recursive component loading concept.

Comment: The Clarity Vertical Nav component only supports one level of child navigation. If your app requires more levels I would suggest combining the vertical nav component with another such as tabs. Take a look at the https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.13/navigation docs to see how that might be done.

Comment: Here is a link to the UX logic behind the decision to only support/recommend two levels of navigation in the vertical nav component: https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/1361#issuecomment-324712679